# Expected shape of Keras Dense layer output with 300 units is (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to have the simples, single layer NN which transforms a vector of 300 numbers to another vector of 300 numbers.

So having:

```
print(np.array(train_in).shape)
print(np.array(train_t).shape)
```

return:

```
(943, 300)
(943, 300)
```

I try the following:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, input_shape=(300,)))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array(train_in), np.array(train_t), epochs=5)
```

I'm getting:

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_37 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (300,)`

Why is target expected to have shape `(1,)`? A layer with 300 units should produce a vector of 300 numbers on output, right?

Edit:

As requested, this is how my data looks like:

```
print(np.array(train_in))
print(np.array(train_t))
```

gives:

```
[[-0.13841234  0.22157902  0.12244826 ... -0.10154381 -0.01824803
  -0.08607237]
 [ 0.02228635  0.3353927   0.05389142 ... -0.23218463 -0.06550601
   0.03365546]
 [ 0.22719774  0.25478157 -0.02882686 ... -0.36675575 -0.14722016
  -0.22856475]
 ...
 [ 0.07122967  0.07579704  0.2376182  ... -0.5245226  -0.38911286
  -0.5513026 ]
 [-0.05494669 -0.3587228   0.13438214 ... -0.6134821  -0.06194036
  -0.46365416]
 [-0.16560836 -0.15729778  0.00067104 ... -0.01925305 -0.3984945
   0.12297624]]
[[-0.20293862  0.27669927  0.19337481 ... -0.14366734  0.06025359
  -0.1156549 ]
 [-0.02273261  0.20943424  0.26937988 ... -0.20701817 -0.03191033
   0.03741883]
 [ 0.16326293  0.19438037  0.12544776 ... -0.37406632 -0.1527986
  -0.29249507]
 ...
 [ 0.05573128  0.26873755  0.40287578 ... -0.65253705 -0.30244952
  -0.68772614]
 [-0.02555208 -0.0485841   0.19109009 ... -0.2797842  -0.01007691
  -0.53623134]
 [-0.30828896  0.04836991 -0.108813   ... -0.20583114 -0.40019956
   0.11540392]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your loss, sparse categorical cross-entropy makes no sense in this case, as it is used for classification, and you do not seem to have a classification problem. To perform regression of a 300-dimensional vector, then mean squared error makes more sense.

The problem with using sparse categorical cross-entropy is that this loss makes the assumption that the model outputs a scalar (a one element vector), and this is checked during runtime, and this check fails and that's why you get an error.

Also, accuracy makes no sense in a regression setting.

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
          loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: Great, thanks, it worked! But could you add to your answer an information, how exactly does choosing cross-entropy or accuracy metricts affects the output shape?

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski sparse cross entropy is the only one that makes the assumption that the output shape is 1, if you use other losses then you won't have this problem. Accuracy doesn't affect this either.

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski No, that's different from what I said, I added an explanation as requested.